# Error when setting up Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to set up Reporting Services on my SharePoint farm however I am getting this error when I try to access the URL:

```
The configuration parameter SharePointIntegrated is set to True but Share Point Object Model cannot be loaded. 
The error was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointServiceHelper..ctor() at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointServiceHelperFactory.get_ServiceHelper() WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. . (rsSharePointObjectModelNotInstalled
```